# What should I do with "implementation method not found" error?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I was working on a react native app and I installed react-navigation library and its dependencies. then after I tried to run my app using Android Studio I get this error:

ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'
Possible causes:
The project 'MealApp' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin

I changed nothing and this error just poped up. What should I do to get rid of this annoying thing?

Comment: Can you share more of your build.gradle file ?

Answer (score 0):

the implementation is support in the Gradle version after 3. try to change it in the `android/build.gradle` as the following

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

At the same time, change the `gradle-wrapper.properties` Gradle version

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```